# Convert string into datime.time, error?

Tags: python

I am getting time data in string format like this, 'HH:MM', for example '13:33' would be 13 hours and 33 minutes.

So, I used this code to get time object and it works great

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('13:33', '%H:%M').time()
```

However, I now have new problem.New strings started coming in representing more than 24 hours and `datetime.datetime.strptime('25:33', '%H:%M').time()` will simply fail.What's your suggestion?

Comment: suggestion for what?  what do you expect to get?  `25:33` is not a time.

Comment: wait, sorry, i see what you mean.  you want an _amount_ of time, like from a stopwatch, right?

Answer (score 1):

A `datetime.time` object represents a (local) **time of day**, independent of any particular day.

You shouldn't use it to represent an elapsed time, like you appear to be.

More appropriate might be a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> A `timedelta` object **represents a duration**, the difference between two dates or times.
>
> `class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])`
>
> All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative.

An example:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(hours=25,minutes=10)
>>> d
datetime.timedelta(1, 4200) #Days, seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it will simply fail", I assume you want to know when it will fail. Here's one approach:

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> time_strs = [
... "13:33",
... "25:33",
... "12:88"
... ]
>>>
>>> for s in time_strs:
...     try:
...         print datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M').time()
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Bad time: {0}".format(s)
...
13:33:00
Bad time: 25:33
Bad time: 12:88
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this manually, alas.

```
def parse_stopwatch(s):
    hours, minutes = s.split(':', 1)
    return datetime.time(hour=int(hours), minute=int(minutes))
```

This is really dumb, granted.  You could automatically have more than 60 minutes convert to hours, or get all fancy with a regex, or add support for days or seconds.  But you'll have to be a bit more specific about where this data is coming from and what it's supposed to represent.  :)